# Entity Framework Error 3004 while trying to add a field into a table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

this question is about adding a new field called "Position" of type integer into an existing table via the Entity Framework designer. What I expect to happen (correct me if I am wrong) is add the field, select to update the database via the model and get the new field created in my database. Instead of this, I get an "Error 3004 Problem in mapping fragments at line xxx". My environment is using Visual Studio 2015 with EF5, and the database is hosted on Oracle MySQL. The project I am working on is a website which was given to me to maintain and upgrade further.

Here are my steps:

#### 1. Discover the table in the model browser, click Show in Diagram.

[image]

#### 2. Inside the model I right-click on the table -> Add New -> New Scalar Property and type the new field "Position" inside the table.

[image]

#### 3. Click save icon to save the model

[image]

#### 4. Then I get an Error 3004:

[image]

#### 5. I realise that in the mapping details my new field isn't showing and I can't type in there to add it manually.

[image]

#### 6. I can see the new field has been added to the syncitem class in fact I want this to be an integer so I go ahead and change it by hand.

[image]

Tried to click save again and re-compile but I still get the same error. I need to say at this point that I have spent an entire day searching around on the web about various error codes I got other than just 3004 but here is where I stopped and turned to SO for guidance. I know there are other threads here about Error 3004 and I did read quite a few them. One of the pieces of advice I found was to change the DDL generation template to one that supports MySQL since Visual Studio will default to SQL (this is done by clicking on the white space inside the designer and then clicking the Properties tab):

[image]

I tried that as well but nothing changed, the error persists... I also tried deleting the entire table in the designer and updating from the database, the table re-appeared but with a torrent of "Error 11007" lines, plus the table's associations are not wired correctly. Another thing I did was to open the .edmx file in Notepad++ and see if I can add my new field in there, but it just felt wrong doing it like that so I quit.

Am I approaching this in the wrong way? All I want to do is add a new field! I have come to a stop, my experience with EF is not great, I felt lots of frustration with this database's particular setup, quite frankly I dare say that I think it is somewhat broken. It's like dealing with a brand new religion whenever I have to touch it!

In the long run I want to upgrade to EF6 and get rid of the designer but that's another story.

Any advice on my problem will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I had to tamper with the XML file of the model (the .edmx file) to manually add in my new field and set it to integer, as there was nothing I could do to satisfy Visual Studio. The web project I am working on looks rather complicated with loads of sub-projects in it like "DataAccess", "EntityModel", "ManagerLayer", my web folders and a host of other directories. I think my EF needs a complete re-do, my guess is that it started with a very old EF version and is shuffling its feet right now in terms of maintainance.